# Jquery not working in php include page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, include

I have a page (form.php) that is called via ajax when a user group is clicked in main page. form.php contains form fields (like date picker etc and other fields as per usertype selection in main page. 
My issue is the when I click on any user type in main page form.php page load using ajax but date picker in this form is not working. I check all path and sequence but its not working.

here is my code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "services/forms.php",
                data: {UserType: UserType},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#assessmentform').html(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can add jquery of datepicker or other on main page and initialize it after ajax response, then it will work

Comment: you have to load the datepicker function on ajax result, or define date picker js load  when body is load.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/services/forms.php",
                data: {'UserType': UserType},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#assessmentform').html(data);
                }
            });
```

try this if this file in outside the services folder

Comment: is it working now? if helped dont forget to accept the ans